# Is there a name for words following this pattern?

Tags: homophones, rhymes

Word pairs like *bizarre* and *bazaar*, although spelled differently sound very similar. It also seems like they are more than just a pair of rhyming words.

Is there a classification within *rhyming words*? Are there other such words? Or are they just a pair of rhyming words and I'm highlighting them because they just sound cool?

Comment: They're called homonyms (also homophones). While the pair you list may in fact be pronounced differently in some dialects, in others there will be no difference.

Comment: Aside from being easily mistakable for each other, there's no real relationship between them.  They even have totally separate etymologies.  

`Bazaar` comes through Italian(`bazarra`) from Persian(`bazar` "market").  

`Bizarre` comes from French(`bizarre`) which possibly comes from either Italian (`bizarro` "angry, fierce, irascible") or Basque(`bizar` "a beard").

Comment: @Robusto I have never heard these two words pronounced the same.

Comment: Basically, what you are saying is that these *don't* rhyme?

Comment: Well, I've heard the endings pronounced the same, but never the beginnings.  There's usually a differentiation in how each is stressed as well.

Comment: Generally, if two words are actually identical in pronunciation, they aren't felt to rhyme. Rhyming requires **some** phonetic difference. Also, the pronunciation varies, so for some people they do rhyme, while for others they don't. Sorry. [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) hasn't gotten around to this one yet.

Comment: Dictionaries show them with the same pronunciation, with a shwa on the first syllable. If the pronunciation is the same, they would be heterographic (spelled differently) homophones (sounded the same).

Comment: Personally I pronounce *bazaar* as "buh-Zahr" and *bizarre* as b'-Zahr", where the "b'" is said with kind of a mostly-unvoiced "i".  They're very close, but not quite the same.

Comment: @Hellion, that is exactly how I would pronounce these words.

Comment: @Hellion: I was just going to tick your comment, but then I realised I pronounce the first vowel in *bizarre* exactly the same as any other similar word where the stress falls on the second syllable *(discover, dissolve, etc.)* I wouldn't say it's "mostly-unvoiced" - it's just the normal unstressed version of the vowel in *sit, big, etc.)*

Comment: @fumblefingers, is there a difference between the way you say "biz" in *bizarre* and "biz" in *business*?  There is for me, even though I think that the 'i' sound in *business* is the same as in *sit, big,* etc.  "Biz" in *bizarre* is more of a "B" with my mouth moving as if to say "i" afterward but without actually putting any air into it, whereas "biz" in *business* is clearly "bizz" with a voiced i. ... When I am enunciating carefully, I probably do say "biz-Zahr", but in normal speech, that 'i' is all but imperceptible.

Comment: The OED gives /bɪˈzɑː(r) for ‘bizarre’ and /bəˈzɑː(r)/ for ‘bazaar’.

Comment: MW gives the same pronunciation for both.

Comment: The [google search for "spelled different sound very similar"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=spelled+differently+sound+very+similar) gives scads of information on this. Did you research it at all first? It would be helpful if you did.

Comment: @Hellion: I think there might be a UK/US difference involved. My UK Chambers agrees with me that *bizarre* and *business* start with the same consonant+vowel, but I note that online (US) MW gives the first vowel as a schwa in *bizarre* - which seems *really* bizarre to me. The finer points about whether preceding/following consonants affect the *exact* sound that comes out are a bit beyond the level we're talking about. But that MW entry represents either a simple mistake or the fact that you Yanks just don't talk proper like us Brits! :)

Comment: @Barrie England: Thank God for another Brit to set them straight! I wonder if it's because Brits are more likely to use/hear the word *bazaar*, so we avoid allowing *bizarre* to adopt a schwa.

Answer (score 2):

Words that sound the same but have different meanings are called [homophones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone).  Homophones can be either

- [homonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) if and only they are spelled the same (e.g. tire - like the thing you put on a car or tire as a verb meaning fatigued)
- heteronyms if they just sound alike, such as your example.

Etymologically, they are usually unrelated (bazaar is Arabic, for instance, wheras bizaare comes from the Latin).  Though they may sound alike, its just an accident.